# Uncaught exception: abort(80) at jsStackTrace - Airconsole Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, request, persistent-storage, unity-webgl, airconsole

When i test a preview of the game in the Developer Console, the following error occurs in the browser. This occurs at the moment when it tries to request persistent data from the player. Someone knows what it is?     NOTE* During development on Windows and in tests with Open Exported Port everything went well.

Complete log:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R4dJx4NSDDMbLirLENz_r0cgoedmS-tk

I would like to get the saved data from the main player with this code.

```c#
public void RequestPersistentData()
{
    List<string> connectedUids = new List<string>();
    connectedUids.Clear();
    connectedUids.Add(AirConsole.instance.GetUID(AirConsole.instance.GetMasterControllerDeviceId()));
    AirConsole.instance.RequestPersistentData(connectedUids);
}
```

First the scene is executed with AirInputManager.cs. Then the main menu scene where the MenuController script is executed is loaded (this is where the error happens). Finally, if the player finishes the game the data is stored on the champion screen where the ChampionManage.cs script runs.

More code: [github](https://github.com/cleitonw1/arenagladiator/commit/1919cfe9a6958f5ec40c6fb455475b18494b9278)

Comment: Please provide more information. We need to see the code that is triggering this error to have an idea of what might be happening.

Comment: Does this part of the code help?

Comment: Not yet, you have to provide <b>all</b> the code that is used to get the data. This includes the `AirConsole` class  and all its methods related to it, this is the only way to track the error

Comment: Ok. I upload to Github. First the scene is executed with AirInputManager.cs. Then the main menu scene where the MenuController script is executed is loaded (this is where the error happens). Finally, if the player finishes the game the data is stored on the champion screen where the ChampionManage.cs script runs.Follow this link: https://github.com/cleitonw1/arenagladiator/commit/1919cfe9a6958f5ec40c6fb455475b18494b9278

Comment: Have you used any debugging tools to check what might be happening when `MenuController` is executed? Because it looks like you have some `find` functions going on Awake. You might have to change the script execution order to make sure everything requested by the `MenuController` on awake is not null

Comment: I will test this. But it is strange that this error only happens when the game is sent to the airconsole store. The objects found are not destroyed during the entire execution of the game. They are created in the first scene.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it that way. In WebGL Player settings -> Publishing Settings-> Compression Format, change Gzip to Disabled. For some reason Gzip takes a long time to extract the necessary files when loading the game. And make sure that the name of the root folder where you will build the project has no blank space. "Crazy Game" (Bad). CrazyGame (Good).

To ensure it will work, make sure that the script execution order responsible for managing AirConsole runs at least -90 in Default Time. You can use the Script Execution Order settings (menu: Edit > Project Settings, then select the Script Execution Order__ category).